# Find and Replace brackets () with new Line in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, replace, find

I have to add some javascript code in VS 2013.

Before (Now)

```
Layout.init();
```

After (What I want)

```
Layout.init();
Side.init();
```

If there were no `()` I could do it with `\n` but VS do not find them.
How can I change them like latter?

edit:
I want to change all my project in every page with ctrl+H;

I can change with ctrl+H and regex enabled:;
find:

```
abc
```

replace:

```
abc
def
```

with this regex
replace:

```
abc \n def
```

when I try to change with `()` VS don't find any of them...

Comment: This is the code which I add some code for all my project..

Comment: Try `\s` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using Notepad++ > 'Find in Files' option to replace text in bulk. It works for files inside a specific directory or if needed, can traverse all sub-directories and replace them. See the below snapshot for settings needed

[image: find and replace of notepad++]

Comment: If it was for one page there is no problem.): I haveto change more thane 30 pages in the project.

Comment: @user4936583, yes, possible. Use 'Find in Files'. See my updated snapshot (Snapshot is of Notepad++, not VS 2013)

Comment: Can I do it for files which in some directory with subs?

Comment: Yes, possible. Check the options as shown in the snapshot and you will be good to go

Comment: great. do you have more than 77 pages where the replacement is expected?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you free **[Multiline Search and Replace](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/699CE302-B0D4-4083-BE0E-1682E873CEBF)** Visual Studio extension. It supports Find/Replace in files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it, I wish tehere were simple solution in VS.